# Error at a comment line

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Hi I have created a stored procedure to a table Persons that is linked to a table Address like this with three foreign keys:

-MaterialAddressID
-HomeAddressID
-PostalAddressID

This is my the stored procedure that I have create:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:  *******************
-- Create date: 11.07.2013
-- Description: Gets User Personal Details
-- =============================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [eConnect].[GetUserPersonalDetails]
        @personId int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT Persons.PersonalID,
               Persons.FirstName ,
               Persons.MiddleName , 
               Persons.LastName ,
               Persons.DateOfBirth,
               Persons.CityOfBirth ,
               Persons.BSN ,
               Persons.SecondaryEmail ,
               Persons.HomePhone ,
               Persons.WorkPhone ,
               Persons.MobilePhone,
               MaterialAddress.StreetName ,
               MaterialAddress.PostCode ,
               MaterialAddress.City ,
               HomeAddress.StreetName ,
               HomeAddress.PostCode ,
               HomeAddress.City ,
               PostalAddress.StreetName ,
               PostalAddress.PostCode ,
               PostalAddress.City
        FROM Sync_Persons as Persons
        JOIN Sync_Addresses as MaterialAddress ON Persons.MaterialAddressID = MaterialAddress.AddressID
        JOIN Sync_Addresses as HomeAddress ON Persons.HomeAddressID = HomeAddress.AddressID
        JOIN Sync_Addresses as PostalAddress ON Persons.PostalAddressId = PostalAddress.AddressID
        WHERE Persons.PersonalID = @personId
    END
```

When I try to exec this I get this error:

> > Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUserPersonalDetails, Line 11 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'I-024800' to
> >     data type int.

Line 11 in this case is : -- Description: Gets User Personal Details

Why am I geting an error at a comment and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line -

```
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(
     Persons.PersonalID, 
     CHARINDEX('-', Persons.PersonalID) + 1, 
     LEN(Persons.PersonalID)
) AS INT) = @personId
```

or try this -

```
WHERE Persons.PersonalID = 'I-' + CAST(@personId AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: Looks like the PersonalID column in Persons could be a computed column from some sequence or identity. Since @personId is already an int that means PeronalID is the value that is 'I-024800' so adding 'I-' would do nothing. If anything the right expression should be changed to 'I-' + CAST(@personId AS varchar(10))

Comment: Yeah well that works but I still think it would be better to change the right expression since the left hold the search expression. Now you are forcing it to compare non indexed values which must first be acquired through casting.